# Question about conjugacy classes in groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove that the conjugacy class ($\overline{a}=\left\{ b\in G/\exists x\in G\,b=x^{-1}ax\right\} $) in a group satisfy that it has only $a$ as element if and only if $a\in Z\left( G\right)$ with  $Z\left(G\right)=\left\{ g\in G\mid ga=ag\text{ for all }a\in G\right\} $

What I've managed to do, (I'm not sure if it's well done) is:

$\left(\Leftarrow\right)$

if $a\in Z\left(G\right)\Rightarrow ax=xa$ $ \forall x\in G$

if $b\in\overline{a}$ with $b\neq a\Rightarrow b=x^{-1}ax=x^{-1}xa=a\Rightarrow b=a$ !!

Any ideas for the other implication?

Comment: It's well-done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to suppose $b\ne a$. Just take $b\in\bar{a}$ and then you get $b=x^{-1}ax=x^{-1}xa=a$.

As for the other direction suppose $\bar{a}=\{a\}$ and let $x\in G$. Then $x^{-1}ax\in\bar{a}=\{a\}$ and hence $x^{-1}ax=a$, which implies $ax=xa$. Since it is true for all $x\in G$ we conclude that $a\in Z(G)$.